# MySQL view returns empty value whether its inner query returns Value

Tags: mysql, view

Hi I am stuck with one my sql view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  view_dr_server_actions_online AS
select
    view_dr_server_actions.dr_request_id as dr_request_id,
    view_dr_server_actions.server_id as server_id,
    view_dr_server_actions.user_action as user_action,
    view_dr_server_actions.action as action,
    view_dr_server_actions.status as status,
    view_dr_server_actions.appliance_id as appliance_id,
    view_dr_server_actions.is_local as is_local,
    view_servers.host_name as host_name,
    view_servers.id as id,
    view_servers.site_id as site_id,
    view_servers.product_key as product_key,
    view_servers.username as username,
    view_servers.password as password,
    view_servers.server_state as server_state,
    view_servers.reachable_state as reachable_state,
    view_servers.dr_plan_id as dr_plan_id,
    view_servers.replication_site_id as replication_site_id,
    view_servers.replication_appliance_id as replication_appliance_id,
    view_servers.local_rpo as local_rpo,
    view_servers.local_rto as local_rto,
    view_servers.remote_rpo as remote_rpo,
    view_servers.remote_rto as remote_rto,
    view_servers.actual_local_rpo as actual_local_rpo,
    view_servers.actual_local_rto as actual_local_rto,
    view_servers.actual_remote_rpo as actual_remote_rpo,
    view_servers.actual_remote_rto as actual_remote_rto,
    view_servers.recovery_sequence_no as recovery_sequence_no,
    view_servers.server_data as server_data,
    get_product_data_of_server(view_dr_server_actions.dr_request_id) as drplan_data
from view_dr_server_actions
left join view_servers on view_servers.id = view_dr_server_actions.server_id
left join view_appliances_online on view_appliances_online.appliance_id = view_dr_server_actions.appliance_id
where server_id is not null
;
```

Above view returns 0 rows but if i run its inner query it returns result .

I am not sure what is happening exactly is that a problem with MySQL please help

Comment: Try running `SELECT` clause from your `VIEW`, check whether it returns some data or not

Comment: i think i mention the same thing in question as inner query it returns result 1 row

Comment: Yes you did, but you need to debug it in so way to find out the problem

Comment: how to debug is there any tool @GauravLad

Comment: What i meant to say is, copy `SELECT` part from `VIEW` and run that part only.
Apart you can try DBForge https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/download.html
for debugging

Comment: select part returning one row @GauravLad

Comment: How you are getting data from `VIEW` i mean what is the query when you run your `VIEW` and it returns no data.